# WiX: preserving recursive directory structure during component transfer

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

Wix 3.11.2 and Visual Studio Community 2019 here. My project has the following directory structure:

```
...\Source\Repos\my-app-setup\
  my-app-setup\
    bin\
    obj\
    testo\
      fizz\
        abc\
          def\
            ghi\
              abba.txt
      buzz\
        bar.txt
      foo.txt
    my-app.exe
    my-app-setup.wixproj
    my-app-setup.wxs
  my-app-setup.sln
```

Where my `my-app-setup.wxs` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">​
  <Product Id="*" Name="MyApp" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="1e540666-dda2-4cbe-91b7-ac9525d96c86">​
    <Package Description="MyApp tool" Compressed="yes" />​
    ​
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>​
    ​
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">​
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">​
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp" />​
      </Directory>​
    ​
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop">​
        <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="*">​
          <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"​
            Name="MyApp"​
            Description="Shortcut for MyApp"​
            Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]my-app.exe"​
            WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>​
          <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>​
          <RegistryValue​
            Root="HKCU"​
            Key="Software/MyApp"​
            Name="installed"​
            Type="integer"​
            Value="1"​
            KeyPath="yes"/>​
        </Component>​
      </Directory>​
    </Directory>​
    ​
    <Component Id="FooTxtComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">​
      <File Source="testo/foo.txt" />​
    </Component>​
    ​
    <Component Id="AbbaComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">​
      <File Source="testo/fizz/abc/def/ghi/abba.txt" />​
    </Component>​
    ​
    <Component Id="ExecutableComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">​
      <File Source="my-app.exe" />​
    </Component>​

    <Feature Id="MainFeature" Title="MyApp" Level="1">​
      <ComponentRef Id="FooTxtComponent" />​
      <ComponentRef Id="AbbaComponent" />​
      <ComponentRef Id="ExecutableComponent" />
      ​
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />​
    </Feature>​
  </Product>​
</Wix>
```

So it basically just copies a bunch of files from the project into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp` directory and then creates a shortcut (to the EXE) on the desktop. Simple stuff.

When I build this and run the MSI the resulting `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp` directory looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
  MyApp\
    foo.txt
    abba.txt
    my-app.exe
```

So WiX is just plucking the files I specified and dropping them into the `MyApp` directory, at the same level as the EXE file. I **don't** want this; I want to preserve the same recursive directory structure as what exists in my VS project. So instead of the above I would like the WiX MSI to generate:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
  MyApp\
    testo\
      fizz\
        abc\
          def\
            ghi\
              abba.txt
      foo.txt
    my-app.exe
```

**What is the simplest way to accomplish this?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the same folder structure, you should do it manually in wix, or use `heat` tool to autogenerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest the folders as shown in this sample (towards bottom): https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with

Illustration:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Example">
         <Component>
              <File Source="example.exe"/>
         </Component>
      </Directory>
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Maybe also check:

- [My WiX Quick-Start Link Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).
- https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/